# Implementing an AVL Tree using smart pointers Part 2

Tags: c++, c++11, avl-tree

I made a similar post on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52564000/implementing-an-avl-tree) but I did not get any useful feedback. I thus tried to re-do my code a bit to see if that would lead to any decent results. So far my code compiles but yet does not print anything and I am not sure why.

I have an example in int main() that should give me a tree that looks like:

```
/* The constructed AVL Tree would be
        9
       /  \
      1    10
    /  \     \
   0    5     11
  /    /  \
 -1   2    6
*/
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>

struct Node {
    int data;
    int height;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> left = nullptr;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> right = nullptr;

    Node(const int& x, const int& y, std::unique_ptr<Node>&& p = nullptr, std::unique_ptr<Node>&& q = nullptr) :
        data(x),
        height(y),
        left(std::move(p)),
        right(std::move(q)) {}

    Node(const int& data) : data(data) {}

};
std::unique_ptr<Node> root = nullptr;

int height(std::unique_ptr<Node>& root) {
    if (!root) return 0;
    return root->height;
}

void fixHeight(std::unique_ptr<Node>& root) {
    auto h1 = height(root->left);
    auto h2 = height(root->right);
    root->height = (h1 > h2 ? h1 : h2) + 1;
}

void rightRotate(std::unique_ptr<Node>& p) {
    std::unique_ptr<Node> q = std::move(p->left);
    p->left = std::move(q->right);
    q->right = std::move(p);
    fixHeight(p);
    fixHeight(q);
}

void leftRotate(std::unique_ptr<Node>& q) {
    std::unique_ptr<Node> p = std::move(q->left);
    q->right = std::move(p->left);
    p->left = std::move(q);
    fixHeight(q);
    fixHeight(p);
}

int heightDiff(std::unique_ptr<Node>& root) {
    if (!root) return 0;

    return height(root->left) - height(root->right);
}

void balance(std::unique_ptr<Node>& root) {
    fixHeight(root);
    if (heightDiff(root) == 2) {
        if (heightDiff(root->right) < 0)
            rightRotate(root->right);
        leftRotate(root);
    }

    if (heightDiff(root) == -2) {
        if (heightDiff(root->left) > 0)
            leftRotate(root->left);
        rightRotate(root);
    }
}

void insert(std::unique_ptr<Node>& root, const int& theData) {
    std::unique_ptr<Node> newNode = std::make_unique<Node>(theData);
    if (!root) {
        root = std::move(newNode);
        return;
    }

    if (theData < root->data)
        insert(root->left, theData);

    else
        insert(root->right, theData);

    balance(root);
}

auto findMin(std::unique_ptr<Node>& root) {
    while (root->left != nullptr) root = std::move(root->left);
    return root.get();
}

void deleteNode(std::unique_ptr<Node>& root, const int& theData) {
    // Step 1: Perform regular deletion for BST
    if (!root) return;
    else if (theData < root->data) deleteNode(root->left, theData);
    else if (theData > root->data) deleteNode(root->right, theData);

    else {
        // Case 1: No child
        if (root->left == nullptr && root->right == nullptr) {
            root = nullptr;
        }

        // Case 2: One child
        else if (root->left == nullptr) {
            root = std::move(root->left);
        }

        else if (root->right == nullptr) {
            root = std::move(root->right);
        }

        // Case 3: Two children
        else {
            auto temp = findMin(root->right);
            temp->data = root->data;
            deleteNode(root->right, temp->data);
        }
    }

    if (!root) return;

    // Step 2: Update height of the current node
    root->height = 1 + std::max(height(root->left), height(root->right));

    // Step 3: Get the balalce factor of the this node (to 
    // check whether this node became unbalanced)
    int balance = heightDiff(root);

    // If this node becomes unbalanced, then there are 4 cases

    // Left Left Case
    if (balance > 1 && heightDiff(root->left) >= 0)
        rightRotate(root);

    // Left Right Case
    if (balance > 1 && heightDiff(root->left) < 0) {
        leftRotate(root->left);
        rightRotate(root);
    }

    // Right Right Case
    if (balance < -1 && heightDiff(root->right) <= 0)
        leftRotate(root);

    // Right Left Case
    if (balance < -1 && heightDiff(root->right) > 0) {
        rightRotate(root->right);
        leftRotate(root);
    }
}

void inorderTraversal(std::unique_ptr<Node>& root) {
    if (!root) {
        inorderTraversal(root->left);
        std::cout << root->data << " ";
        inorderTraversal(root->right);
    }
}

void preorderTraversal(std::unique_ptr<Node>& root) {
    if (root != nullptr) {
        std::cout << root->data << " ";
        preorderTraversal(root->left);
        preorderTraversal(root->right);
    }
}

void postorderTraversal(std::unique_ptr<Node>& root) {
    if (root != nullptr) {
        postorderTraversal(root->left);
        postorderTraversal(root->right);
        std::cout << root->data << " ";
    }
}

void DFS(std::unique_ptr<Node>& root) {
    if (!root) return;

    std::stack<Node const *> s;
    s.push(root.get());

    while (!s.empty()) {
        auto p = s.top();
        s.pop();

        if (p->right != nullptr) s.push(p->right.get());
        if (p->left != nullptr) s.push(p->left.get());

        std::cout << p->data << " ";
    }
}

void BFS(std::unique_ptr<Node>& root) {
    if (!root) return;

    std::queue<Node const *> q;
    q.push(root.get());

    while (!q.empty()) {
        auto p = q.front();
        q.pop();

        if (p->left != nullptr) q.push(p->left.get());
        if (p->right != nullptr) q.push(p->right.get());

        std::cout << p->data << " ";
    }
}

bool exists(int d) {
    auto temp = root.get();
    while (temp != nullptr) {
        if (temp->data == d) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            if (d > temp->data) {
                temp = temp->right.get();
            }
            else {
                temp = temp->left.get();
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {

    //        8
    //      /    \
    //    4       10
    //   / \     /  \
    //  2   6   9    12

    //insert(root, 8);
    //insert(root, 10);
    //insert(root, 4);
    //insert(root, 2);
    //insert(root, 6);
    //insert(root, 12);
    //insert(root, 9);


  /* Constructing tree given in the above figure */
    insert(root, 9);
    insert(root, 5);
    insert(root, 10);
    insert(root, 0);
    insert(root, 6);
    insert(root, 11);
    insert(root, -1);
    insert(root, 1);
    insert(root, 2);

    /* The constructed AVL Tree would be
            9
           /  \
          1    10
        /  \     \
       0    5     11
      /    /  \
     -1   2    6
    */

    printf("Preorder traversal of the constructed AVL "
        "tree is \n");
    preorderTraversal(root);

    //deleteNode(root, 10);

    /* The AVL Tree after deletion of 10
            1
           /  \
          0    9
        /     /  \
       -1    5     11
           /  \
          2    6
    */

    //printf("\nPreorder traversal after deletion of 10 \n");
    //preorderTraversal(root);

    /*inorderTraversal(root);
    std::cout << "\n";

    preorderTraversal(root);
    std::cout << "\n";

    postorderTraversal(root);
    std::cout << "\n";

    DFS(root);
    std::cout << "\n";

    BFS(root);
    std::cout << "\n";

    exists(4) ? std::cout << "Yes" << std::endl : std::cout << "No" << std::endl;*/


    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Please provide a link (or URL) to that "similar post". Read also [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Done, see edit

Comment: I strongly recommend compiling with all warnings and debug info `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` and using a recent [`gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/). Don't expect us to do your homework. Debugging skills are an essential part of C++ programming

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I know I am asking for help on debugging this as I have not practiced myself enough, could you please help me on this one?

Comment: No. I recommend using the `gdb` debugger, and I won't do that for you. I also recommend reading *carefully* some [*Introduction to Algorithms*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms), and that takes months. StackOverflow is *not* a debug-my-code site. [AVL tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree)s are a difficult data structure (I studied it 30 years ago, and forgot the details; even for me, it is not trivial to re-implement them). You need to budget several weeks of efforts to debug your code

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I understand I am a mathematician trying to become better at programming and I am currently reading cracking the coding interview and The Algorithm Design manual. I just started reading these a few weeks ago so I am new at these types of data structures.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Should I just delete this question then?

Comment: I won't delete that question *now* (but perhaps later). You need to understand your bugs, understand in *details* all the invariants on AVL trees (I learned that 30 years ago, but forgot the details), and check that your code is following them by using a debugger. You'll find that something is wrong in your code (but you need to understand, with a debugger, the actual behavior of your own code)

Comment: When coding in C++, using a debugger is not a luxury you may avoid. It is an essential tool. You also need to compile with all warnings, and improve your code to get none. I simply cannot understand why you don't use a debugger (and if there is some valid reason for that, you should explicit it in your question)

Comment: In *addition* of a debugger and your GCC compiler with all warnings, you might even use static source code analyzers like [Clang-Analyser](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) or even [Frama-Clang](https://frama-c.com/frama-clang.html). But there is [*No Silver Bullet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Silver_Bullet), whatever tools you will use, you'll need weeks of efforts

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yes, unfortunately I do not have weeks.

Comment: I am sorry for you. I recommend using a debugger. With good luck, you might find your bug in only a few days. Otherwise, you have failed your project (and this happens *very* often in software development). But my belief is that *without* a debugger, you won't find your bug (and you should *not* expect us to find it). I still don't understand what forbids you to use a debugger.

Comment: If you are a mathematician (I am not, but I have been trained in math, my Master degree -1985-  was on applied mathematics and computer science; I was taught about [distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)), got a good score at exams on them, forgot everything about them since that time), you might be interested in [formal methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_methods). But even if you use them, you still should also use a debugger when coding in C++; and I know that formal methods are not a silver bullet...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Neat! thank you!

Comment: ... but I am working as a research engineer in a formal methods lab (the one making [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/)....) of 40 persons. I am probably the most skeptical guy about formal methods in practice in that lab. They are *not* a sliver bullet! Common sense is still needed for software development

Comment: However, could you explain to us (and to me), in a few sentences, why you are forbidden to use a debugger when coding in C++. I am very curious about that (since this is highly unusual).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch To be honest, I have no idea where to begin and what to look for in the case of using a debugger. I never really debugged before formally besides commenting out code and running it line by line to see where my code goes astray.

Comment: My opinion is that you absolutely need to improve your practical skills and learn how to use a debugger. In practice, that is not very hard. http://norvig.com/21-days.html gives very useful insights on. the practical skills related to software development. I don't understand how you can assess the behavior of your program without any debugger. Please explain!

Comment: Read also about [the law of leaky abstractions](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2002/11/11/the-law-of-leaky-abstractions/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I have been able to get through it without using one dont really know what to explain

Comment: A more practical approach is to *trust* your C++ standard library (people implementing it are quite clever). Then you just could use some standard [container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) such as `std::map` or `std::set` which implements some kind of [self-balancing binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree), perhaps AVL ones.

Answer (score 2):

At the first place the `insert()` function will not work. Initially when the AVL tree is empty, root = nullptr. Every time it will return void without inserting any new node. It should look something like this.

```
void insert(std::unique_ptr<Node>& root, const int& theData) {
    if (!root) { 
        root.reset(new Node(theData,0));
    }
    else {
        if (theData < root->data)
            insert(root->left, theData);
        else
            insert(root->right, theData);
            balance(root);
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I see, if you see the old post I made above I have an insert() function that was similar to deleteNode but it still didn't work for some reason.

Comment: Insert code reedited to add height parameter . preorderTraversal now prints correctly.

Comment: It did not compile for me throws this: Exception thrown: read access violation.
std::_Unique_ptr_base<Node,std::default_delete<Node> >::_Myptr(...) returned 0x8.

Comment: Yes, now it seems to work and comment out the insert(root, 2) why does it work now when I do that?

Comment: You need to fix some flaws in the balance. TODO?